# Excel is only pasting part of my range, and erroring out on the rest. How do I fix this?

Tags: vba

I'm building a macro that lets the user select a folder, select which tab to import, then it opens up every file in the folder, grabs all of the data in the given tab, and imports it into one main sheet for easy review.

It's breaking in an interesting way - when it's pasting the data in with the line

```
DestinationWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & LastrowOutput).Resize(DataRng.Rows.Count, DataRng.Columns.Count).Value = DataRng.Value
```

It's posting in some of the data, then generating the error message "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" For specifics, in my first file I have 15311 lines by DD columns. It imports 14832 lines as it generates the error message.

(Going to test with fewer columns)

Additionally, when debugging and stepping through, it jumps from the If statement directly to the problem while generating the problem and all of the data.

There is nothing unusual in the data at the lines given.

Am I hitting some technical limit? Does anyone know what's going on? My google-fu is failing me.

Edit: When running the code again with data in the tab, I manage to get to row 29663 before getting an "Automation error" error message. Still working on that column test...

Edit 2: Got it to only select the columns in question. Still breaks on the same row.

Edit 3: Broke up the code to do the first 10,000 rows, then all of the remaining rows. Still breaks on the same line. It was suggested that I look for hidden rows and columns - There are no hidden rows or columns. Going to try value2 and value3 next.

```
Sub PullingAllData()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim sPath As String
Dim sFil As String
Dim FolderPath As String
   Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
   Dim DestinationWorkbook As Workbook
   Dim DataRng As Range
   Dim LastrowInput As Double
   Dim LastrowOutput As Double


    'Open the file dialog
  Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show
    FolderPath = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

     ' Cycle through spreadsheets in selected folder




    Set DestinationWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

     Dim ImportTabNumber As Integer
ImportTabNumber = InputBox("Please Enter the tab to import.*", "Account Name")


sPath = FolderPath & "\" 'location of files

sFil = Dir(sPath & "*.xlsx") 'change or add formats
Do While sFil <> "" 'will start LOOP until all files in folder sPath have been looped            through


Set owbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & sFil) 'opens the file

If owbk.Sheets.Count >= ImportTabNumber Then

        Set InputTab = owbk.Sheets(ImportTabNumber)
        LastrowInput = InputTab.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set DataRng = InputTab.Range("A1:DO" & LastrowInput).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


  LastrowOutput = DestinationWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  DestinationWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & LastrowOutput).Resize(DataRng.Rows.Count, DataRng.Columns.Count).Value = DataRng.Value

End If



owbk.Close True
sFil = Dir

Loop

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot use Rows.Count on a multi-area range to get the total number of rows: it will just return the number of rows in the first area.  So your code will fail if there are hidden rows in the input range.  You also cannot assign values from a multi-area range to another range just using the `rng1.Value = rng2.Value` approach.

Comment: So I've broken it up into two parts now - if there's more than 10,000 lines, give me the first 10k then everything that's left. STILL breaks at the same line. Lastrowoutput is therefor giving me a value of 10002 (As expected), with 5311 rows and 25 columns - all numbers that I expect and hope to see. There are no hidden rows or columns - good idea to check.

Comment: So I decided to throw out the current file it kept pulling and try with the remaining files. It's currently running well. Bad data causing an issue?

Comment: Hard to say....

Answer (score 2):

This post (specifically the answer by Cees Timmerman near the bottom) may shed some light on the issue. It is also worth checking if you have a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Excel. If you have the former, you may be running out of memory.

If you have the latter, try creating a `Variant` array to store the data before transferring it (`Dim MyData as Variant : MyData = MyRange.Value`).

I would also recommend opening up your task manager and checking the performance tab. You should be able to use the resource monitor to track how much RAM is being used. RAM is very unlikely to be the source of the issue if you do have 64-bit, but it doesnt hurt to see what is happening behind the scenes (and how expensive that operation *can* be).

Before putting that code into production though I highly recommend more tests (with more files). If that code is already breaking, it will be very likely to break again in the future.

Comment: RAM usage is normal. Does the memory issue still make sense when on my first file, I was breaking at the same line when I broke up the data into several smaller chunks?

Comment: And I just got a file where I did get an out of memory error - so it seems like when memory is the issue, I get a separate error

Comment: Upvoting for that last paragraph. Do not put fragile code into production... figure out why it "sometimes" breaks so you can make sure it "never" breaks.